# npm package compatible with older version of its package dependency

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I installed typescript into my existing vuejs project using the command `vue add typescript`. It added the following dependencies and presets into the application.

```
"typescript": "~3.8.3", 
"@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.3.1",
"vue-class-component": "^7.2.3". 
"preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel"
```

It also changed "vue-property-decorator" from "^7.2.0" to "^8.4.1". However AWS-Amplify depends on "vue-property-decorator": "^7.2.0" and my system is throwing several errors related to the same. 
How can I find a typescript version that is compatible with "vue-property-decorator": "^7.2.0"?

Comment: `"typescript": "^3.5.2"`, from that projects `package.json`.

Comment: thank you @DigitalDrifter, that fixed my issue. God Bless.